# How to connect to both sides

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, connect-by

I'm trying to get all the ascendants and the descendants of a List of IDs.
It's like a directory-tree where the list of IDs are the directory with access rights including sub-directorys. To navigate to the folders I also need the ascendents.

I tried to UNION ascendents and descendent but if I do so I have no correct SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH results, because the ascendents are upside-down.

My table has a ID, Name and Parent_ID.

Is there a chance to get this work?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results; and preferably what you tried and why it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `connect_by_path` and modify it's behavior using CTE:

```
with c(id, name, parent_id, direction, list) as (
  select id, name, parent_id, 0, name from t where name = 'A1'
  union all
  select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, 
         case t.parent_id when c.id then 1 else 2 end,
         case when t.parent_id = c.id 
              then c.name||'/'||t.name
              else t.name||'/'||c.name
         end
    from c join t on (direction in (0, 1) and t.parent_id = c.id) 
                  or (direction in (0, 2) and c.parent_id = t.id))
select * from c
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=231f46337184d453f471b9be80045c70)</sup>**

Depending in which direction I move I concatenate list differently.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide test data, I used the EMP table. I created a view on EMP to translate to your column names.

This solution goes from **one** starting point:

```
create or replace view v_emp(id, parent_id, name) as
select empno, mgr, ename from emp;

with target_emp as (
  select name, id, parent_id
  from v_emp 
  where name = 'JONES'
)
, descendants as (
  select connect_by_root(parent_id) id,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, '/'), 2) descendant_list 
  from v_emp
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with parent_id = (select id from target_emp)
  connect by parent_id = prior id
)
, ancestors as (
  select connect_by_root(id) id,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, '/'), 2) ancestor_list
  from (
    select id, name, parent_id, level lvl
    from v_emp
    start with id = (select parent_id from target_emp)
    connect by id = prior parent_id
  )
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with parent_id is null
  connect by lvl = prior lvl - 1
)
select ANCESTOR_LIST, name, DESCENDANT_LIST from target_emp
left join ancestors on 1=1
left join descendants on 1=1;

ANCESTOR_LIST   NAME    DESCENDANT_LIST   
KING            JONES   SCOTT/ADAMS        
KING            JONES   FORD/SMITH
```

Try this starting with 'KING', 'JONES', 'SCOTT' then 'ADAMS'.

Best regards,

Stew Ashton

Answer (score 1):

This answer starts from every row in V_EMP. Note that I am producing paths because you mentioned SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH. If you want some other kind of output, please be more specific. The best would be to show expected output using EMP or data that you provide.

```
with descendants as (
  select connect_by_root(parent_id) id,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, '/'), 2) descendant_list
  from v_emp
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with parent_id is not null
  connect by parent_id = prior id
)
, ancestors as (
  select root_id,
    substr(sys_connect_by_path(name, '/'), 2) ancestor_list
  from (
    select connect_by_root(id) root_id,
    id, name, parent_id, level lvl
    from v_emp
    where level > 1
    connect by id = prior parent_id
  )
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with parent_id is null
  connect by root_id = prior root_id
    and lvl = prior lvl - 1
)
select a.ancestor_list, e.name, d.descendant_list
from v_emp e
left join descendants d on e.id = d.id
left join ancestors a on e.id = a.root_id
order by a.ancestor_list nulls first, e.name, descendant_list;

ANCESTOR_LIST      NAME     DESCENDANT_LIST  
-------------      -----    ---------------
                   KING     BLAKE/ALLEN          
                   KING     BLAKE/JAMES          
                   KING     BLAKE/MARTIN         
                   KING     BLAKE/TURNER         
                   KING     BLAKE/WARD           
                   KING     CLARK/MILLER         
                   KING     JONES/FORD/SMITH     
                   KING     JONES/SCOTT/ADAMS    
KING               BLAKE    ALLEN                
KING               BLAKE    JAMES                
KING               BLAKE    MARTIN               
KING               BLAKE    TURNER               
KING               BLAKE    WARD                 
KING               CLARK    MILLER               
KING               JONES    FORD/SMITH           
KING               JONES    SCOTT/ADAMS          
KING/BLAKE         ALLEN                         
KING/BLAKE         JAMES                         
KING/BLAKE         MARTIN                        
KING/BLAKE         TURNER                        
KING/BLAKE         WARD                          
KING/CLARK         MILLER                        
KING/JONES         FORD     SMITH                
KING/JONES         SCOTT    ADAMS                
KING/JONES/FORD    SMITH                         
KING/JONES/SCOTT   ADAMS
```